# How do I pass "ref" to children in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My question is how can I pass a ref prop to children in my component?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```js
import React, {
  Children,
  createRef
} from "react";

const Form = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = createRef();
  console.log("ref: ", ref)
  return (<>
    {
       Children.map(children, (child) => {
         return cloneElement(child, { ...child.props, ref })
    } 
  </>)
}

const Input = forwardRef( (props, ref) => {

}) => {
   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      getCustomAttr(){
         return "example";
      }
   }))
}

--------------------------------------------------
<Form>
   <Input />
</Form>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

I was expecting the ref variable not to be null

Comment: [This example should explain things well](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useImperativeHandle#usage)